# ASP.Net MVC 4 Redirecting onSessionStart to an Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my Global ASAX I detect a condition and if not met, I go to the **Login** Action on the **Account** Controller.

```
    void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(thingy==null)
            Response.Redirect(Request.ApplicationPath + "/Account/Login");
    }
```

Is there a way to get the URL of the Login action on Account at this stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session.IsNewSession)
        Response.RedirectToRoute("LogOn", "User");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. I'm looking though for the url of the Login Action on the Account Controller. I don't want to hard code it.

Comment: do you want to use appsettings or just a url.action() solution?

Comment: Url.Action, but that doesn't seem to be available at the Global.assx